# aria-labelledby references id that isn't present in DOM (yet)

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I wish to provide accessibility information about a form input using aria-labelledby.  This property accepts an id list (space delimited) that will contain, naturally, the id of the label element that is 'for' the form input.  However, I wish to also include one or more additional ids for elements that may dynamically be added to the form later.

When I run an audit against my markup using https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools it informs me that "ARIA state and property values must be valid".  If I re-run the audit after adding the element with the id that referred to nothing, the test passes.

My question is **will screen readers barf if they come across an id that points to no element currently in the DOM?**  I'm not so much caring about the audit results directly (they're there to help me, but aren't my client in the end).

*Mainly I want to know if I can stuff ids in there that I know may be present later on, or if I should update the property's value *when I add and remove the elements I want to reference*.

Comment: as an aside, I hope it's ok to preemptively put them there.  The library I'm using that adds and removes the elements in question doesn't support callbacks for when that happens, so it'd be a pain :(

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on this bit of code, but IIRC I did find how to hook the addition/removal of the element, so I think I went that route and did end up updating the id list when the elements were added/removed.

Comment: Every screenreader in my experience has simply ignored the unassociated IDs. Can't help but feel this is solving for a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very idea of the attributes is to help users and make the page more accessible, so it would be against the very idea to refer to nonexistent elements with them. If the attribute is *used* at all, it will be used to refer to elements in a manner that matters to the user, so of course there can be trouble – even if the assistive software or the browser handles the error the best possible way.

It is also formally incorrect, because the attribute has been declared as containing `id` attribute values, and a string cannot be such a value when the `id` attribute does not exist.

So, you should simply make your script modify the attribute value to contain an `id` attribute value as soon as you have added that value, but not sooner.

Comment: If screen readers simply ignore the unassociated IDs (as they should, and which every one has in my experience), what's the harm in just leaving them on or the benefit in adding extra logic for functionally equivalent behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Screen readers won't "barf", but the experience for the user may be odd. That's the important issue, right? You can check that out yourself using VoiceOver (included with MacOS) or [NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org) (free for Windows).

Comment: do you know of a specific oddity?  If I specify 'idA idB' and idB doesn't exist will it read idA and then say something indicating it couldn't find idB, or just pause for a bit?  I suppose I need to bite the bullet and learn to use NVDA :)  thanks for pointing me to that.  it's good to know there's a free reader available.

Comment: It's been a few months since I did screen reader testing, so I don't have an answer at the moment.